# What is the origin of the term "bull****" in its figurative sense?

Tags: etymology, offensive-language, phrase-origin

When/how did the word "bullshit" or the phrase "I call bullshit" (or its multiple variants) become acceptable in English? Was it a direct adaptation from another language or was it introduced in some other manner?

(Please note that I am just referring to the use of the term in everyday general banter as questioning disbelief and not its literal usage in reference to cow dung.)

Comment: Interesting question. But just to clarify, are you concerned with _acceptability_ (ie weakening of  taboo)? Or are you just interested in 'where it came from', whether taboo or not?

Comment: I was interested in its origins, I had no idea that the term was old enough to have been considered taboo in general speech

Comment: Casualcoder, you used 'acceptable' which I interpreted as non-taboo. Did you mean 'when did bullshit come to mean what it does today?' ?

Comment: @mich yes I was looking at when it became non-taboo

Comment: @jsw29 I was more interested in how the figurative meaning came to be, if there is a link between the literal and figurative meaning which lead to it, I would be interested in knowing it.

Comment: @casualcoder it's a metaphor. When people say "You're talking rubbish" they're not saying that your words are literally things to be thrown away. But the intention is clear.

Comment: @mitch I know what it means, I'm looking more at when/how it became so, the current answer already explains that I just to reading it

Comment: casualcoder, I was answering the question you had in your comment to @jsw29: "how it came to be" "if there is a link". I can't imagine anything more than a straightforward explanation of the metaphor of disliking gross things that you want to avoid.

Comment: @jsw29 so the question is why this particular thing, the excrement of a bull, _as opposed to something else_ ? Like why not 'cowshit'? or 'dogshit'? That's not clear from the OP but is that what _you_ are asking now?

Comment: @jsw29 Some arbitrary looking things may well be chosen arbitrarily. It could have been some drunk uncle just picking one thing out of many, chickenshit was already taken and bull's seem bigger, let's go with that. Or multiple people chose different things, and 'bullshit' won slowly, well before anything was put into print. Most things don't have answers like 'it happened here on this date'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The Online Etymology dictionary describes Bullsh*t thus:](https://www.etymonline.com/word/bullshit)

> "eloquent and insincere rhetoric," 1915, American English slang; see bull (n.1) + shit (n.), probably because it smells. But bull in the sense of "trivial or false statements" (1914), which usually is associated with this, might be a continuation of Middle English bull "false talk, fraud" (see bull (n.3)).
>
> [bull (n.3)](https://www.etymonline.com/word/bull?ref=etymonline_crossreference)
>
> "insincere, trifling, or deceptive talk," 1914. Popularly associated with roughly contemporary bullshit (n.) in the same sense, and in modern use often felt as a shortened form of it. There seems to have been an identical Middle English word meaning "false talk, fraud," apparently from Old French bole "deception, trick, scheming, intrigue," and perhaps related to modern Icelandic bull "nonsense."
>
> Sais christ to ypocrites ... yee ar ... al ful wit wickednes, tresun, and bull. ["Cursor Mundi," Northumbrian, early 14c.]
>   There also was an early Modern English verb bull meaning "to mock, cheat," which dates from 1530s. Bull session is attested from 1920.
>
> Also of uncertain connection with the bull that means "a gross inconsistency in language, a ludicrous blunder involving a contradiction in terms" (1630s), said by the English to be characteristic of the Irish, and thus often called an Irish bull. Sydney Smith defined it as "an apparent congruity, and real incongruity of ideas, suddenly discovered." Three examples attributed to Sir Boyle Roche: "Why should we do anything for posterity, for what, in the name of goodness, has posterity done for us?" ... "It would surely be better, Mr. Speaker, to give up not only a part, but, if necessary, even the whole of our Constitution, to preserve the remainder." ... "The best way to avoid danger is to meet it plump."

[The Routledge dictionary of modern American slang and unconventional English](https://thariqalfathih.files.wordpress.com/2015/04/ulrlklwnrnekihejaojl-signature-13e671e7ce00256288168433c3e3892dc737b7bd85e3450f6bb8fe797ddcf76d-poli-141104171516-conversion-gate01-1.pdf) appears to confirm the 1914 meaning of the word (pp. 140 & 141)

[image: BS 1]
[image: BS 2]
[image: BS 3]

Further interesting observations about the 1914 reference appear in this [wordwizard](http://www.wordwizard.com/phpbb3/viewtopic.php?t=6143) discussion:

> Most dictionaries say that ‘bullshit, utter nonsense, a flagrant lie, flattery, insincere talk is an American expletive first recorded in 1914, but many etymologist feel that it was in use at least a century before that. The ubiquitous 1914 date appeared in the supplement to the 1972 OED (repeated by almost all dictionaries) – a pretty late appearance for such a widely used (by then) term. A quotation from **a 1914 letter** **James Joyce wrote to Ezra Pound** read: “**I enclose a prize example of bullshit**.” A 1915 letter of Joyce to Pound read: “ [T.S.] Eliot has sent me Bullshit & the Ballad for Big Louise. They are excellent bits of scholarly ribaldry.”

The [Strong Language](https://stronglang.wordpress.com/2015/01/02/when-shit-hits-the-newspapers/) blog has also carried out some research about the term in their article "When “shit” hits the newspapers".

[This mentalfloss article](http://mentalfloss.com/article/502300/19-old-timey-ways-call-bs) discusses 19 Old-Timey ways to call B.S.

The blog [Escaping from Bullshit](http://ditext.com/wordpress/category/using-the-word-bullshit/) covers the term almost exclusively

Answer (score 0):

I don’t know
whether Google Ngram Viewer is a good arbiter of “acceptable” English,
but, FWIW, it indicates that “bullshit” seems to have started its climb
in the mid-1960s:

[image: Google Ngram Viewer: bullshit vs. horseshit]
[Google Ngram Viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=bullshit%2Chorseshit&year_start=1940&year_end=2010)

I recall hearing “horseshit” used to mean
pretty much the same thing as “bullshit”
(although, perhaps, slightly less forcefully);
Google confirms that “horseshit” is about 5% as prevalent as “bullshit”. 
It seems to me that I haven’t heard it much since 1980,
although Google indicates that it continued to gain in popularity past 2000.

And “horseshit” seems to be used ***way*** more frequently
than any other common one-syllable animal I could think of:

[image: Google Ngram Viewer: horseshit vs. lesser animals]
[Google Ngram Viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=horseshit%2Cdogshit%2Cbirdshit%2Cpigshit%2Ccatshit%2Csheepshit%2Cgoatshit&year_start=1940&year_end=2010)